# Best driver for PHP database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was just wondering the asnwer to this question..
for a few select, insert, and update querys with only a mysql database which driver is the best? MySQL, MySQLi or PDO for speed?

Comment: Use PDO. Not for speed, but for abstraction and safety.

Comment: ^ Yes, and also for all the other benefits it yields. To answer the question, PDO is _slightly_ slower than mysql functions, but is vastly superior and should not be abandoned for the fact that it benchmarks at a slightly slower speed.

Comment: If you will use prepared statement (you should) you will hate mysqli, especially migrating to php 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use the `mysql_*` functions, that API is depreciated.
- [MYSQLi](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/) is a replacement for MYSQL and also comes with object-oriented and procedural versions.
- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (PHP Data Objects) is fairly advanced and is a general database abstraction layer with support for MYSQL among other databases.

---

### How to learn PHP, PDO and MYSQLi

- Documentation for programming languages
- Stack Overflow community
- Programming Books
- YouTube Channels

**Code Course** is an excellent resource to learn PHP. Try his [website](https://www.codecourse.com/) and [YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/phpacademy).

Good luck! :)

**UPDATE: Comparing the Speeds**

- MYSQLi is slightly faster than PDO and makes programming easy if your familiar with the *mysql_** extension
- PDO is not as fast as MYSQLi. However, it offers much easier transition to other databases. It also offers more features (eg. named parameters in prepared statements, object mapping).

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, which one is faster?

Comment: I have updated my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am more concerned over speed due to it being such a small project, and 90% of them features wont be used.

Comment: Good luck on your project! Make sure to accept this answer when you have the chance...

Comment: Do you have any information on the speed differences between MySQLi and PDO?

Comment: I know that MYSQLi is slightly faster than PDO. I don't know the exact speed difference. Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL extension is essentially retired (as of PHP 5.5 or thereabout). Thus, in my opinion, since you are using a MySQL db, you have your choice from the other two (MySQLi supports MySQL only, PDO is MySQL plus a dozen other DB flavors).

Given what you are doing, I don't believe there is going to be significant difference in performance. Some benchmarks indicate that MySQLi is a smidge faster than PDO (depending on what you're doing), so if you really need to squeeze for every millisecond, I'd probably go for MySQLi.